# Run python code and logging the output also want to grep specific string to stop

Tags: bash, tee

Hi I want to run the python code and logging output also want to when output contain specific string and kill the process

I knew the command that "run python code and logging output"
`python run.py 2>&1 | tee output.log`

but I don't know how to grep the specific string and kill the process.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to modify `run.py` accordingly. If this is not an option, the closest you can get is using the `-m` option of `grep`:

```
python run.py 2>&1 | tee output.log | grep -m 1 YOUR_PATTERN
```

After `grep` gets the first match, it will exit and with this close the pipe to `tee`. After that pipe is closed, tee will eventually (i.e. the next time it is time to flush its output buffer) detect that the output pipe is gone and exit, and with this close the pipe to `python`. When `run.py` is flushing its output buffer, it detects that the pipe is gone and terminate. Due to this buffering and parallelism of the three processes, it takes some time between `grep` finding the pattern and `python` actually terminating itself.